# Attempting to migrate junit framework from dagger1 to dagger2

Tags: java, junit, dagger-2

I've been trying to find a suitable way to migrate our current test automation library from using dagger1 to dagger2, but I'm struggling with the general concept, as dagger2 doesn't allow for covariance.

I've read through every article I could find, but I'm fairly new to dependency injction. The examples I've read through make sense, but they don't seem to cover a situation like the one I'm facing now.

I've been trying to wrap my head around the general concept of how Components may fit into this particular design, but I fear I may be overlooking something obvious. I'm open to an overhaul if necessary, but I'd prefer it be a last resort.

Any examples or links to helpful resources would be greatly appreciated.

---

Here are code snippets of the original (dagger1) design.

**The AutomationJUnitRunner Graph Instantiation**

```
@Override
protected Object createTest() throws Exception
{
  Object test = super.createTest();

  if(test instanceof RequiresInjection)
  {
    WebDriverModule module = new WebDriverModule(capabilities, isProxiedWebDriver);
    LOGGER.trace("create test called " + test.getClass().getSimpleName() + " - " + module.provideBrowserName());
    ObjectGraph objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(concat(getModules((RequiresInjection) test), module));
    objectGraph.inject(test);
  }
  return test;
}

private Object[] getModules(RequiresInjection requiresInjection)
{
  Object modules = requiresInjection.getModules();
  return modules instanceof Object[] ? (Object[]) modules : new Object[] { modules };
}

private Object[] concat(Object[] modules, Object module)
{
  Object[] result = Arrays.copyOf(modules, modules.length + 1);
  result[modules.length] = module;
  return result;
}
```

**Sample Dagger1 Original Test Class and Test Module**

```
@RunWith(AutomationJUnitRunner.class)
public class LoginTest implements RequiresInjection
{

    @Inject
    @Rule
    public WebDriverRule webDriverRule;

    @Inject
    LoginNavigator loginNavigator;

    @Inject
    Credentials credentials;


    @Test
    public void login()
    {
        LoginPage loginPage = loginNavigator.getLoginPage();
        DashboardPage dashboard = loginPage.login(credentials.getUsername(), credentials.getPassword());

        assertThat(dashboard.isVisible(), is(true));
    }

    @Override
    public Object getModules()
    {
        return new TestModule();
    }


    @Module(injects = LoginTest.class, includes = { WebDriverModule.class }, overrides = true)
    public class TestModule
    {
        Credentials provideCredentials()
        {
             return new Credentials("exampleuser", "examplepass");
        }

    }
```

---

**Dagger2 attempt - Test class and Test component**

```
@RunWith(AutomationJUnit4Runner.class)
public class LoginTest implements AutomatedTest
{

    @Inject
    @Rule
    public WebDriverRule webDriverRule;

    @Inject
    LoginNavigator loginNavigator;

    @Inject
    Credentials credentials;


    @Test
    public void login()
    {
        LoginPage loginPage = loginNavigator.getLoginPage();
        DashboardPage dashboard = loginPage.login(credentials.getUsername(), credentials.getPassword());

        assertThat(dashboard.isVisible(), is(true));
    }


    @Override
    public void inject(AutomationComponent automationComponent)
    {
        LoginTestComponent c = DaggerLoginTest_LoginTestComponent
                .builder()
                .automationComponent(automationComponent)
                .build();

        c.inject(this);
    }

    @Component(dependencies = { AutomationComponent.class }, modules = { CredentialsModule.class })
    public interface LoginTestComponent
    {
        void inject(LoginTest loginTest);
    }
}
```

**Dagger2 attempt - Test Runner, Test Instantiation**

```
    @Override
    protected Object createTest() throws Exception
    {
      Object test = super.createTest();

      if (test instanceof AutomatedTest)
      {
        WebDriverModule module = new WebDriverModule(capabilities, isProxiedWebDriver);
          LOGGER.trace("create test called " + test.getClass().getSimpleName() + " - " + module.provideBrowserName());

          ConfigurationComponent cc = DaggerConfigurationComponent.builder().build();
          WebDriverComponent wdc = DaggerWebDriverComponent.builder().webDriverModule(module).build();

          AutomationComponent automationComponent = DaggerAutomationComponent.builder()
                  .configurationComponent(cc)
                  .webDriverComponent(wdc)
                  .build();

          ((AutomatedTest) test).inject(automationComponent);
      }
      return test;
    }
```

Comment: You need to specify concrete classes in order to use `void inject(`

Comment: EpicPandaForce is right here. If you want to inject variables into your LoginTest class, you need to have
void inject(LoginTest test);

Comment: Ty! I've got a working prototype in place now. I'll get the examples updated, as I'd like to eliminate as much boilerplate as possible.